# Raspberry pi 3 indicates booting, but no USB or HDMI output

Tags: debian, raspbian-buster

I'm new to stack exchange so my question might not be the best.

My raspberry pi 3 b+ 2015 (I have had it for 4 years) that I use regularly has a problem with booting.

I booted it up this morning and the led went on, but nothing was outputted - I had '''no signal''' on the monitor and the keyboard LEDs did not light up. The led in the pi indicated that it was running well. It is running a wiki, so I went on my phone and typed in the ip. There wasn't anything there. The server automatically starts on startup. I don't know what's wrong.

Thanks in advance ✌️

Comment: *"The led in the pi indicated that it was running well"* -> By this I presume you mean that the green ACT light is flashing sporatically to reflect access to the SD card.  If you instead mean it is on solid constantly, that is not a sign it is running well, that is a sign it is not running at all.

Comment: So what would the led indicate if it was working?

Comment: You can't have a "pi 3 b+ 2015" because the Pi3B+ wasn't released until 14 Mar 2018. Even the Pi3 wasn't released in 2015

Answer (score 0):

> The led in the pi indicated that it was running well.

If the green led just comes on and stays on, it isn't booting at all.  It will probably do the same thing with no card in -- try it. Although I think the 3(+)'s I have do the opposite (light never comes on for no SD card), I do no know whether this depends on model number or something else.

Normally, the green led indicates the SD card is being accessed.  So it will flash rapidly and irratically at boot, and thereafter reflect the state of the system. Unless you are using it as a busy database or file server, once relevant stuff is loaded into memory, that activity should die down.

A wiki does potentially make a lot of regular database access depending on how big it is and how active users are.  But if it cannot be reached online, it probably should fall into inactive after not very long.  If instead it is flickering endlessly, it may be stuck in some issue at boot.

You should have a look at the root filesystem logs in another computer and see if there are any clues about what is happening there.  *Note that if the green LED is flashing in a very regular, repeated pattern, this means something else again.*  However, that is pretty obvious.

Comment: It hosts a wiki and a forum, but I'm the only one using it (for testing purposes) and it is not available for anybody - just people on the lan. I will check bootlogs and led again, but you might want to know that I am using berryboot, as that may cause a few problems as it has before.

Comment: I have checked the pi, and it seems to flash green 3 times and then stops for a second and does it again. What does this mean?

Comment: http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Green_LED_blinks_in_a_specific_pattern It is probably because of SD card corruption.  Check the first (boot) partition (this is true regardless of what OS, berry boot, etc. you are using) in another machine, see if it can be read properly and what is in it.

Comment: I have formatted sd after many attempts and failure, hopefully it will work.

Comment: The error was a faulty partition that my server somehow made. Fixed now. Thank you!